# What is the radial function of a Minkowski sum of a circle and an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, convex-geometry

[image: Minkowski sum of circle and ellipse]

---

Let $C$ denote the unit circle in the two-dimensional plane, centered at the origin (the blue circle in the pic). Let $E$ an ellipse whose equation is $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$. The set $C+E$, known as the Minkowski sum of $C$ and $E$, is defined by
$$C+E=\{\vec{\alpha}+\vec{\beta}: \vec{\alpha}\in C,\ \ \vec{\beta}\in E\}$$
In the picture above, the orange oval-shaped enclosing figure is the boundary of the sum $C+E$,
(where for the sake of this example, $E$ is the ellipse with $a=2,b=1$). The green ellipse in the picture is 
$Q+E$, where for the sake of example, $Q=(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$. The point $P$ represents a typical boundary point of the sum $C+E$, which is the orange oval, which is the geometric location of all points obtained by rotating around the green ellipse with its center varying along the blue circle.
The point $O$ is the origin $(0,0)$ and the point $M$ is the orthogonal projection of $P$ onto the $x$ axis.

> > **Problem: Express the length of $\vec{OP}$ in terms of the angle POM.**

I can prove that if $$F(\varphi)=\arctan\left(\tan\varphi \frac{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\varphi+b^2\sin^2\varphi}+b^2}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\varphi+b^2\sin^2\varphi}+a^2}\right),\quad (0\leq\varphi\leq \pi/2)$$
Then if the angle POM is $\theta$, then the angle QOM is $F^{-1}(\theta)$ (the inverse function), and then it is not too difficult to express the $\vec{QP}$ in terms of $F^{-1}(\theta)$ and consequently the length of $\vec{OP}$ in terms of $\theta$ (and $a,b$ of course).  However, the result seems to be too complicated; I suspect there might be a simpler geometric argument that escapes me.

Comment: $C + E$ is a part of the envelope of the family of curves $F(x, y, \phi) = 0$ describing ellipses with centers at $(\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$. Eliminating $\phi$ from $F = \partial F/\partial \phi = 0$ gives the equation of the envelope. Converting to polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$ gives $P(r^2) = 0$, where $P$ is a degree $4$ polynomial with coefficients depending on $\theta$. The largest positive root of $P(r^2)$ gives $C + E$ (another positive root corresponds to the part of the envelope lying inside $C + E$).

Comment: What approach did you take so far? Are you looking for an explicit formula or just a concept that is simple at a high-level?

Comment: So far I have parametrised the boundary of the sum $C+E$ by using the gradient of the support function of $C+E$, which is simply the sum of the support functions of $C$ and $E$, respectively. This allowed me to derive the formula alluded to in my post. Perhaps there is no easy way out.

Answer (score 2):

HINT

Since Minkowsky sum is commutative, then the alternative order of the calculations can be proposed.

[image: Minkowsky sum]

The point of the circle farthest from the ellipse is located on the normal to the ellipse.

Denote 
$$\angle xOQ = \varphi,\quad \angle xOP = \theta.$$

Parametric equation of the ellipse is 
$$x=a\cos\varphi,\quad y=b\sin\varphi,$$
the guide vector of the tangent line is $\{-a\sin\varphi,b\cos\varphi\},$ and the angle coefficient of the line $QP$ is
$$k=\dfrac ab\tan\varphi.$$

Then
\begin{align}
&\overline{OQ}=\{a\cos\varphi,b\sin\varphi\}, \\[8pt]
&\overline{QP}=\dfrac1{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\{1,k\}
=\dfrac{\{b\cos\varphi,a\sin\varphi\}}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}},\\[8pt]
&\overline{OP} = \overline{OQ}+\overline{QP}\\
&=\left\{\left(a+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}}\right)\cos\varphi,
\left(b+\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}}\right)\sin\varphi\right\}\\
&=\sqrt{\left(a+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}}\right)^2\cos^2\varphi 
+ \left(b+\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}}\right)^2\sin^2\varphi}\\
&\times\{\cos\theta,\sin\theta\},\\[8pt]
&\left(a+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}}\right)^2\cos^2\varphi
=\cos^2\theta\\
&\times\left(\left(a+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}}\right)^2\cos^2\varphi 
+ \left(b+\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}}\right)^2\sin^2\varphi\right),\\[8pt]
&\left(a\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}+b\Large\mathstrut\right)
\cos\varphi\sin\theta
=\left(b\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}+a\right)\sin\varphi\cos\theta,\\[8pt]
&(a\cos\varphi\tan\theta-b\sin\varphi)\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi} =a\sin\varphi - b\cos\varphi\tan\theta,\\[8pt]
\end{align}

$$\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}
=\dfrac{a\sin\varphi - b\cos\varphi\tan\theta}{a\cos\varphi\tan\theta-b\sin\varphi},\tag1$$

$$(a\tan\theta-b\tan\varphi)^2(a^2\tan^2\varphi+b^2)
 = (a\tan\varphi - b\tan\theta)^2(1+\tan^2\varphi),\tag2$$
and fourth-order algebraic equation has known exact solution
$$\tan\varphi = f(\tan\theta).$$

Also from $(1)$ should
$$a+\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}}
= a+b\,\dfrac{a\cos\varphi\tan\theta-b\sin\varphi}
{a\sin\varphi - b\cos\varphi\tan\theta}
= (a^2-b^2)\dfrac{\sin\varphi}{a\sin\varphi - b\cos\varphi\tan\theta},$$
$$b+\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2\varphi+b^2\cos^2\varphi}}
= b+a\,\dfrac{a\cos\varphi\tan\theta-b\sin\varphi}
{a\sin\varphi - b\cos\varphi\tan\theta}
= (a^2-b^2)\dfrac{\cos\varphi\tan\theta}{a\sin\varphi - b\cos\varphi\tan\theta},$$
$$OP = (a^2-b^2)\dfrac{\sin\varphi\cos\varphi\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}{a\sin\varphi - b\cos\varphi\tan\theta},$$
$$OP = (a^2-b^2)\dfrac{\sin\varphi}{a\tan\varphi\cos\theta - b\sin\theta}.\tag3$$

Formulas $(2),(3)$ define required result.

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{About\ equation\ (2).}}$

Substitutions 
$$t=a\tan\varphi-b\tan\theta,\quad \tan\theta = p\tag4$$
present equation $(2)$ in the form of
$$(a^2p - b(t+bp))^2((t+bp)^2+b^2) = t^2(a^2+(t+bp)^2),$$
$$\Bigl(((a^2-b^2)p - bt)^2-t^2\Bigr)((t+bp)^2+b^2) = (a^2-b^2)t^2,$$
$$(b^2-1)t^2((t+bp)^2+b^2) = (a^2-b^2)\Bigl(t^2+p(2bt-a^2+b^2)((t+bp)^2+b^2)\Bigr),$$
$$(b^2-1)t^4+2bp(2b^2-a^2-1)t^3
+\Bigl(b^2(b^2-1)(p^2+1)+p(a^2-b^2)^2-a^2+b^2\Bigr)t^2$$
$$+2bp(a^2-b^2)(p(a^2-b^2)-b^2(p^2+1))t +pb^2(a^2-b^2)^2)=0,\tag5$$

If formula $(5)$ is correct for the given parameters' values, then it should be reduced to the form of
$$g(t)= t^4+2pt^3\pm q^2t^2+2rs+\pm s^2=0.\tag6$$

And the presentation
$$g(t) = (t^2+pt)^2 - (rt+s)^2,$$
taking in account 
$$q^2 = q^2(\cos^2\beta+\sin^2\beta)= q^2(\cosh^2\gamma-\sinh^2\gamma),$$
allows to obtain unknown $\gamma$ via suitable cubic equation and to deal with the quadratic ones.

Proposed approach looks hard, but I do not see more effective way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you write down a formula for the function $f$ in the equation $\tan\varphi=f(\tan\theta)$?

Comment: @uniquesolution The standard way exists in the handbook (Abramowitz, Stegun). I have not full formulas, but I have shown my favourite approach.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts. Your answer is in fact more complicated than mine, and I was looking for something quite different. However, You have put considerable effort in your results, so you can have the 300 points.